# Hierarchical query DB2

Tags: database, db2

Can't execute query in ibm db2 on cloud. At first I tried SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, but it returned with *An unexpected token "PRIOR"*

```
SELECT ID0, MNAME, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(MNAME, '/') AS PATH
FROM MAIN WHERE ID0 IN (40,60) CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID0=MAIN_ID;
```

Second attempt was my code from SQLite which worked well, but not now, it says *Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or function "MNAME"*

```
WITH paths (id, path) AS (SELECT id0, Mname FROM main WHERE main_id IS NULL 
UNION SELECT id0, path || '/' || Mname  FROM main inner join paths on main_id = id) 
SELECT id, path FROM paths where id in (40,60);
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I've made it, at least I hope it's correct

```
WITH paths (id, path, counter) AS
(  SELECT id0, Mname, 1 
   FROM main
   WHERE main_id IS NULL 
UNION all
   SELECT id0, path || '/' || Mname, counter + 1
   FROM main, paths
   WHERE main_id = id and counter <=100
) 
SELECT id, path
FROM paths
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: CONNECT BY is Oracle syntax but it is supported in Db2 as well when DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR = 08 is set. As you already discovered in a recursive CTE the old join syntax is needed in Db2 LUW. 
Hint: I recommend adding a counter with a stop condition to avoid endless loops.